# Why can't i compare this two string ? The string input is the same, but it always return false

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I got the random password generator program from here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138703/simple-random-password-generator 
And then I wanted to make a simple password program. Which generate 3 random char and uses sprint to combine "REG-" with the 3 random char.

```
REG-xxx
```

but the program doesn't compare it the way I expect it to do so. Do I miss some unexpected elements in the array ? Because I have read that char arrays counts newline or space as its elements too, Thanks in advance.
Here's my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(){

    int i;
    srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));
    char pass[6];
    char codebook[10];
    char password[10];

    printf("Press enter to get a three-character password\n");
    getchar();

    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        pass[i] = rand() % 9;
        char capLetter = 'A' + (rand() % 26);
        pass[i + 2] = capLetter;
        char letter = 'a' + (rand() % 26);
        pass[i + 3] = letter;
        printf("%d%c%c\n", pass[i], pass[i + 2], pass[i + 3]);
        sprintf(codebook, "REG-%d%c%c\n", pass[i], pass[i+2], pass[i + 3]);
    }
    system("pause");
    printf("%s\n", codebook);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter the password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);
    printf("\n%s\n", password);
    printf("%s\n", codebook);
    system("pause");
    if(strcmp(codebook , password) == 0){
        printf("password is correct\n");
    } else{
        printf("password is false\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pease show example of input and output.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` This might not do what you think. It is implementation depending.

Comment: Try `printf("\n#%s#\n", password);` and similar for codebook, to make sure that you can tell when whitespace is involved.

Comment: @Yunnosch hey your debug solution is very useful, I found my error already hahaha, cheers man. I thought fflush(stdin); would remove any white spaces, is it actually not ?

Comment: Flushing input is not defined in the standard and might or might not do what you expect.... But in this case it would not have helped either way of course.

Comment: ahh i see, i recognized the difference, thank you once again tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you print a newline into the password

```
sprintf(codebook, "REG-%d%c%c\n", pass[i], pass[i+2], pass[i + 3]);
```

You can later not enter that newline into the password and hence the comparision fails.

Changing to

```
sprintf(codebook, "REG-%d%c%c", pass[i], pass[i+2], pass[i + 3]);
```

solves the problem.

To find this kind of problem with whitespace in strings, I recommend to debug by printing the strings framing them in "impossible" but printable characters. As I recomended in a comment, I found the problen by introducing some additional prints (or modifying existing ones):

In this case, the helpful one was directly after the problematic `sprintf()`:

```
printf("#%s#\n", codebook);
```